# Delphi onkeydown event response

Tags: delphi, keydown

I want to get response from Form while pressed and holding a key,how do I do that ?
I wrote code for 'OnKeyDown' but that works only once per press/

Comment: What "response" do you want?  Describe the behaviour you are trying to achieve.  More specific is better than less specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want OnKeyPress, not OnKeyDown.

KeyPress will continue to trigger as long as you hold the key down.

Comment: Strange,but OnKeyPress and OnKeyDown don't trigger, only OnKeyUp works fine in my project

Comment: Have you set KeyPreview:=True; in your form's OnCreate?

Comment: Yes,I set it in Object inspector panel.

Comment: I learned that the KeyPress event is not raised by noncharacter keys,i want to control a ball with arrow keys,so that it should keep moving while i hold the key,how that could be done?